# How can I enter the directory with prefix '-t'

Tags: linux, directory

By mistake, I create a directory with the prefix '-t' on a Linux server. For example, `-train-20200514-081411`. When I want to `cd -train-20200514-081411`, there is an error:

```
-bash: cd: -t: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir]
```

So in this case, how can I use this directory?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53017/how-do-you-enter-a-directory-thats-name-is-only-a-minus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
cd -- -train-20200514-081411
```

The `--` tells `bash` not to interpret any more items as flags, example transcript below:

```
[~]: mkdir -- -turkey; ls
-turkey  other_file.txt

[~]: cd -- -turkey

[~/-turkey]: cd ..

[~]: rmdir -- -turkey; ls
other_file.txt
```